# Does Dead Space 3 for PC support the Xbox 360 Controller?

Tags: controllers, dead-space-3

I'm trying to decide which version of Dead Space 3 I should buy. I'd rather have it for PC, but only if I can use an Xbox 360 Controller natively. I'm not interested in using mapping software. Does Dead Space 3 support the Xbox 360 Controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Dead Space 3 can be played natively with the xbox controller, it even supports hot swapping from controller to k/m or vice versa.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I bought an Xbox Controller, and it works! Just make the buttons, and you are ok!

Comment: What do you mean be "make the buttons"?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, but you may encounter frequent crashes when using a controller. I'm not sure why, or if there's a fix for it, but for some reason, Dead Space 3 doesn't like it when you use a controller...

Comment: I have not had this problem with my setup.